# A form with fields that are associated with different database tables does not pass validation and does not create the necessary record in the db

Tags: python, html, django

I need to create an object in a database table using the form. This table is linked to other tables by means of a One-to-Many relationship. that is, through the ForeignKey. The fields are filled in by means of a drop-down list, which displays the objects that are in the tables associated with these fields. When I try to send data from the form, it does not pass validation and does not send anything.

forms.py:

```
class receiptForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['is_apartment'].empty_label = "Не выбрано"
        self.fields['is_owner'].empty_label = "Не выбрано"
        self.fields['is_receipt_type'].empty_label = "Не выбрано"

    

    class Meta:
        model = receipt
        fields = ['is_apartment', 'is_owner', 'is_receipt_type', 'date', 'receipt_file']
```

views.py:

```
def create(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = receiptForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('main')
        else:
            error = "Форма была неверной"

    form = receiptForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }
    if (request.GET.get('error')): return render(request, "main/main.html", context={'error': request.GET.get('error')})
    return render(request, "main/main.html", data)
```

models.py:

```
class apartment(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField("Адрес квартиры", max_length=500, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class owner(models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField("Фамилия", max_length=50, default="")
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=50, default="")
    middle_name = models.CharField("Отчество", max_length=50, default="")
    email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.surname} {self.name} {self.middle_name}'

class receipt_type(models.Model):
    pattern = models.FileField("Шаблон", upload_to='pattern')
    title = models.CharField("Название квитанции", max_length=50, default="")
    description = models.TextField("Описание", max_length=300, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class meter_reading(models.Model):
    price_per_unit = models.IntegerField("Цена за единицу")
    number_of_units = models.IntegerField("Кол-во единиц")
    start_date = models.DateField("Время начала периода")
    end_date = models.DateField("Время конца периода")
    apartment = models.ForeignKey('apartment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    types = [
        (1, 'Вода'),
        (2, 'Газ'),
        (3, 'Электричество'),
    ]

    type_of_service = models.IntegerField("Тип", default=1, choices=types)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.apartment} | {self.start_date}->{self.end_date} | {self.type_of_service}'

class receipt(models.Model):
    is_apartment = models.ForeignKey('apartment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_owner = models.ForeignKey('owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    is_receipt_type = models.ForeignKey('receipt_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField("Время выписки", null=True)
    receipt_file = models.FileField(upload_to='receipt', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.is_apartment} | {self.is_owner} | {self.is_receipt_type} | {self.date}'
```

Form in the template:

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
                    
     <p class="text-light">Тип квитанции: {{ form.is_receipt_type }} </p>
     <p class="text-light">Адрес: {{ form.is_apartment }} </p>
     <p class="text-light">Плательщик: {{ form.is_owner }} </p>
     <p class="text-light">Дата: {{ form.date }} </p>
     <p class="text-light">Файл: {{ form.receipt_file }} </p>
     <span class="text-light">{{ error }}</span>

     <button class="btn btn-success mt-5" type="submit">Создать</button>
     </form>
```

I have already tried to display the form in different ways, to do different **init** methods, and I did not understand how the queryset parameter works.

Comment: Why are you making up your own error message instead of using the actual validation errors on the form?  Those will tell you what really went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work by changing the template and the view

In the template:

I put those fields like `form.is_receipt_type` outside of the form because it was causing problems, I'm not sure why they are there in the first place...

I rendered the form using `{{ form }}`

```
<p class="text-light">a Тип квитанции: {{ form.is_receipt_type }} </p>
    <p class="text-light">b Адрес: {{ form.is_apartment }} </p>
    <p class="text-light">c Плательщик: {{ form.is_owner }} </p>
    <p class="text-light">d Дата: {{ form.date }} </p>
    <p class="text-light">e Файл: {{ form.receipt_file }} </p>

<h1>START FORM</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        {{ form.errors }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form }}
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-5" type="submit">Создать</button>
</form>
```

in the view made these changes:

```
def create(request):
    form = receiptForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse("good")

    data = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "test.html", data)
```

as mentioned in a comment above to show the errors use `{{ form.errors }}`